# Federal and State Road Information

Tags: data-request, data.gov, transportation

I am looking for a data set that determines geo-tagged location for federal and state roads and can also decipher which roads are not classified as federal or state roads.

Any ideas where this information could be sourced from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the national highway system you will find all the locations/polylines in the National Highway Planning Network dataset at:

http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/2014/polyline

You will also find a girth of geocoded data related to the national transportation system (hubs, railways, airports, etc) under the Bureau of Transportation Statistics - Geospatial Information

http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/subject_areas/geographic_information_services/index.html

As far as state routes, I think you will still have to get that data from each state's transportation or geographic survey sites. Here's a few:

**Kansas:** http://gisinventory.net/GISI-5224-Road-and-Street-Centerlines---Highways---This-dataset-is-a-single-centerline-highway-network-representation-of-the-10000-miles-Kansas-State-Highway-System-(Interstate-U.S.-and-Kansas-routes)..html

**Minnesota:** http://www.dot.state.mn.us/maps/gdma/gis-data.html

**New Jersey:** http://www.state.nj.us/transportation/gis/metadatafaq.shtm

**New York:** https://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/inventories/member.cfm?OrganizationID=539

**Utah:** http://gis.utah.gov/data/sgid-transportation/roads-system/

If you end up compiling all the state data together, I recommend placing it in github for the benefit of all.

UPDATE: I had forgotten that I had a web page with a collection of state transportation sites (lol):

http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/traffic.php

One may also find other transportation related data portals at the crowdsourced catalog of open data portals (I am a co-founder of) by selecting the category Transportation:

http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata

Comment: your welcome. I added some more resources (see UPDATE).

Comment: possibly worth a mention is open addresses on github, but i could be entirely wrong here

Comment: @albert - thx for mentioning this resource. I had not seen it before.

Comment: @Andrew-OpenGeoCode oh man, i'm kind of embarrassed on this. aside from beneficial, i bet you can really help out. url for anyone interested https://github.com/openaddresses/openaddresses

Comment: u.s. parcels datasets http://www.fairview-industries.com/page7/page7.html